# Replace variable markers with values from dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a function that takes a string and a dictionary as input. 
The string will be like `Hello <name>` and the function will return Hello value 
where value is the mapping of character in the dictionary. How could I write a function to replace all such variable occurrences?  
I couldn't find any way of writing a regex that would allow me to loop over the variables in angular brackets and replace them with dictionary values in python.

Sample Input and Output:

##### Key is the template, value is the expected output:

```
variables={
    "name": "Mars",
    "pet": "dog",
    "age": 22, 
}
```

#### Test cases.

```
test_cases={
    "Hello <name>!" : "Hello Mars!",
    # "Good day, <name>. You look happy <name>": "Good day, Mars. You look happy Mars",
    # "Good day, Miss": "Good day, Miss",
    # "Hello <name>. How is your <pet>": "Hello Mars. How is your dog",
    # "Hello <name>! I am <age>": "Hello Mars! I am 22",
    # "Hello <name! I am <age>":"Hello <name! I am 22",
    # "Hello <name!": "Hello <name!",
    # "Hello name>! I am <age>":"Hello name>! I am 22", 
    # "Hello <<name>>!" : "Hello <Mars>!",
}
```

**My Thoughts:** 
I have tried simple looping over the string, and when a < is encountered, I store the characters in a separate variable till > is encountered and 
 then fetch the value from the dictionary and add it to the final string. This seems to be working with some minimal flaws. But it gets messy with a lot of nested if-else statements

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your inputs and expected outputs? Please read through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: @JanWilamowski, I have added the input-output cases and also mentioned my approach. Please let me know if anything else is required

Comment: You could try using f-strings
```python

f"Hello {variables['name']}. You look happy {variables['name']}. How is your pet, {variables['pet']}?"   --->   'Hello Mars. You look happy Mars. How is your pet dog?'
```

Comment: @dnaiel yes, please also add your current code. I assume you want to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace values using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). The pattern contains a matching group (the part between the angular brackets) which can be used to look up the corresponding value in your `variables` dict:

```py
text = "Hello <name>!"

result = re.sub(r'<([^>]+)>', lambda match: variables[match.group(1)], text)
```

gives `'Hello Mars!'`.

You can also extract the replacement function to make it a bit clearer:

```py
def replace(match):
    keyword = match.group(1)
    return variables[keyword]

result = re.sub(r'<([^>]+)>', replace, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was asked in one of my interview question.
And this code runs perfectly.

````
import re

def templatize(template, variables):

    tmList=[]
    for line in template.split(' '):
        pattern=re.findall(r'<\w.+?>',line)
        if pattern:
            tmList.append(pattern)
    tmList=[item for sublist in tmList for item in sublist]
    for item in tmList:
        key=item[1:-1]
        value=variables[key]
        template=template.replace(item,str(value))
    return template```
````